# Vue/Cli - Vue3 Special Character Problems

Tags: vuejs3, vue-cli

I am writing an application with vue/cli. I use special characters in many places. (Example: Öö-Çç-İı-Üü-Şş-Ğğ) but these characters are not what I want (I write "This is an example" but it says "This is an �xample").

��� I couldn't understand why?

I was try ;

1-

```
<html lang="tr">
```

2-

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-3">
```

3-

```
   <meta charset="utf-8">
```

but it still didn't work.

```
npm run lint
```

When I run the command, it still converts special characters into "�". I think this faulty situation is due to webpack or vue/cli.